# How do you join many PNG images adjacently in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, png, image-processing

I'm new to photoshop and this commmunity. I have 25 images in PNG format, grayscale, 2100 x 2100 pixels and ~50 KB in size.

Is there a way to merge the images consecutively in a single PNG file without increasing file size or losing the orginal quality of each image?

I already tried creating a 25*2100 x 2100 canvas to Place every image and manually order them in CS6. But the resulting file (after merging layers) became huge (~300 MB), PS didn't even let me save it in PNG format. Hope you guys can give me a better solution, one that ideally results in a file of size 25*~50 KB.

Comment: Hi Israel, Welcome to GDSE! Can I ask why you want to join these PNGs in the way you describe? That would result in an image 52,500 pixels wide—which is huge. And wouldn't be supported by most programs. Regardless of the huge size, it's also not reasonable to expect to combine 25 images and not have a significant filesize increase.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: No you can not do this. But you can arrange it into a square. Though its still going to suck as a solution. Use a video format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack the images one atop the other: 
Create a new image and pull each of your images into consecutive transparent levels of that single file. Now you have a stack of prepared images, probably with transparent background, which will provide your desired outcome when the system flattens them when saved as the format you desire. Save the original with layers in Photoshop for future editing and accessing the component images.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the canvas size to be that big, you could try using File>Export>Save for Web. If you pick PNG-8 you can change the amount of colors used. By reducing this number, you lower the file size. Using GIF instead of PNG-8 allows you to reduce the filesize even further.

You will also lose image quality though, and I think it isn't realistic to expect a (25*2100) x 2100 file to be 50 kB max. Is there any specific reason that you need it to be 50kB max?

Comment: I'd have to calculate to be sure, but if most of the images are whitespace, 50 Kb expanding to 52,000 x 2,500 might *just* be possible ... However, in this case the original images are ~50Kb *each*.

Comment: Save for Web has a max size limit.. Not sure what it is but you can't Save for Web a 52,000 x 2,500 image.